# Is "If it is rain tomorrow" incorrect?

Tags: grammar, expressions

Why is this incorrect?

> If it is rain tomorrow, we won't go to the park.

and why should it be this?

> If it rains tomorrow, we won't go to the park.

[edit]Now I added 'Why' in hope it's understood as needing help. 
Well, I didn't know the sentence is so obviously incorrect, and I still don't understand why. Please help me.

Comment: Both the sentences are grammatically correct.

Comment: @Khan: I beg to differ - the first one is certainly not.

Comment: @karlalou I think someone might've mistaken your question as a proofreading question. To me, it's quite clear that it's a grammar question.

Comment: @Stephie: I beg to differ. There would obviously be at least an *implicit* reference to a weather forecast, but *grammatically* I can't see anything wrong with *It's rain tomorrow, but then it'll be sunny for the rest of the week*. And even if someone can find an argument to support the idea of that not being "grammatical", the fact of the matter is it's used all the time by native speakers. Many of whom (myself included) would not balk at the minor changes involved in OP's version above.

Comment: @Stephie I agree with Fumble. "It's rain tomorrow" isn't a common way to express the idea, but it is probably grammatically ok. The first thing I thought of was  the expression "rain or shine".

Comment: @ColleenV: Yeah - I certainly didn't mean to imply these usages are *common*. My advice to learners would be not to bother about them too much, or try to integrate them into some more general principle. I suppose ***Come rain or shine** tomorrow, we're going* is some kind of "fixed" construction (cf *come hell or high water* and perhaps others), but you could reasonably allude to that usage (whimsically? facetiously?) with, say, *If it's rain or shine tomorrow, we're still getting married!*. (Or whatever :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this sentence is confusing is the ambiguous "it is".  Depending on what the listener believes you are referring to, the sentence may take on different meanings.

> "The forecast for today is 'rain' again."
>
> "If it (the forecast) is 'rain' tomorrow, we won't go to the park."

In this case, "rain" is a quote about the weather.  Since it is a quote, it does not have a tense and is correct.

> "(The sky) is raining."
>
> "If it (the sky) rains tomorrow, we won't go to the park."

Now we are talking about an action that the sky is taking - it has rained, it will rain, or it is raining.  Since we are talking about a state that the sky will be in for some time, we say "it rains".

The reason that the first sentence ("if it is rain") sounds wrong to a native speaker is that they are assuming rain is a verb associated with "it" and thus should be conjugated as such.

Comment: I got it. Thanks. So when 'it' is used as the subject of the sentence when talking about the weather, the 'it' is the sky! and the weather is the sky's action. Thus 'rain' should be in verb form.

Comment: Yes, but I think it's worth pointing out that strictly speaking, the "it" in "it's raining" isn't *actually* "the sky", just as it's not "the air" in "it's foggy", or "the sun" in "it's sunny". *And* that nobody actually *says* "the sky is raining" in normal circumstances.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Absolutely correct!  I am also open to suggestions as to what "it" means in this context, because for the life of me I have no idea...

Comment: It's the "generic **it**", or whatever you want to call it. It's not always necessary that you should be able to *identify* what **it** actually is in any given usage (you'd have *real* problems trying to do that with the first word of this very sentence! :)

Answer (score 4):

> > 1. *If it is rain tomorrow, we won't go to the park. (ungrammatical)
> > 2. If it rains tomorrow, we won't go to the park.

Example (1) is ungrammatical when *RAIN* is a verb. Usually, when we talk about the weather tomorrow, we use a verb, NOT a noun. We don't say:

- *Tomorrow is rain. (ungrammatical, uses a noun)

**Talking about the present**

The verb *RAIN* usually uses the word *it* as a subject:

- **It's raining** today.

In this example we see the Present Continuous *is raining*. This is because the raining action is happening *NOW*. Notice that we use *is* and an *-ing* form of the verb together.

If we want to say that it rains generally, usually, or often, we use the Present Simple:

- **It rains** a lot in London.

Notice that the verb rain has an 'S' here. Also, there is no verb *is* in this sentence. We don't use *BE* (am/is/are) as an extra verb in the Present Simple.

**Talking about the future**

When we want to say that the weather will be rainy tomorrow, there are different ways to do this. If we saw the weather forecast on the television, then we can say:

- It's raining tomorrow.

If we saw the weather forecast, OR if we just have an idea that it's going to rain, or someone told us, we can say:

- It'll rain tomorrow. (It will ...)

[There are some other ways too, but they aren't very important for us now.]

**Conditionals (The future and *if*)**

In sentences beginning with *if* or time prepositions like *when, before, after, until* the sentence often has two parts, two clauses:

- If A, B.
- When A, B.
- After A, B.

We can also make these sentences the other way:

- B if A.
- B when A.
- B after A.

The important grammar here is that we do not like to use *will* in the A section. We don't like to use *will* after words like *if, after, when*. We usually use a normal present tense of the verb.

We can use *will* in the B section:

- When I see you tomorrow, I will buy you dinner.
- After the concert finishes, I will go home.
- If you're coming tomorrow, we will have a great time.

**The Original Poster's examples**

The original Poster wants to say they won't go to the park in rainy weather. They are using a sentence with *if* to talk about the future. If they have seen the weather forecast they can say:

3. If it's raining tomorrow, I won't go to the park.

Notice that this example uses the present continuous. We need the verb *BE* ('s) and the *-ing* form of *RAIN*.

If the speaker wants to say:

- If + [It will rain tomorrow] = I won't go to the park

... then they need to change the first sentence, because we don't like to use *will* after *if*. We need to use the present simple:

4. If it rains, I won't go to the park.

Notice that we have two choices. Sentence (3) uses *is raining*, the Present Continuous. Sentence (4) uses *rains*, the Present Simple. We can use "*is* + *-ing*" OR we can use just the main verb "*rains*". But! We cannot mix them. We cannot use the verb *BE* ('s) and *-ing*! The following example is wrong:

- If it is rains ..... (ungrammatical. It uses *BE*, but doesn't use *-ing*)

*Hope this is helpful!*

Comment: Yes it's helpful. So you say "If it's raining tomorrow, …" because you believe the weatherman and almost sure it will rain, right? It's nice to know the way progressive tense is used. Even I know that 'If it is rains' is no good though. Now I'm wondering how to say it when it's sunny in the same way like 'If it rains'. 'If it shines'? I guess I have to post another query.

Comment: @karlalou No, we usually say *if it's sunny*. So we usually use the adjectives *sunny, cloudy, windy*. There is an adjective *rainy*, but we hardly ever use it! We use the verb *RAIN* instead! :)

Comment: I would have corrected the first example simply by adding an -y. "If it is **rainy** (*sunny*, *windy*, *cloudy* etc.)  tomorrow" sounds grammatical to me.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, that's a good point!

Comment: I see from the comments you already mentioned *rainy*, why did you not include it in your answer?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Just because I don't think we say it very much, really. That and the fact that it's quite difficult to explain the difference between ascriptive and specifying uses of *BE*, eg "this is heat" versus "this is hot" :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Or maybe it is very easy, but I'm not very good at it. One of the two ...

Comment: Not very common, but [*if it is rainy*](https://www.google.it/search?q=%22it+is+rainy%22&oq=%22it+is+rainy%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.14892j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#tbm=nws&q=%22if+it+is+rainy%22) is used in the news.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments, both are fine. However, I would say that the second one:

> If it rains tomorrow, we won't go to the park.

sounds much more natural to me. I would be happy with, and would understand

> If it is rain tomorrow, we won't go to the park.

but I would always favour the prior (the first one).

Comment: Or alternatively, "if it's raining tomorrow, we won't go to the park."

Answer (score 0):

((Why is this incorrect?

If it is rain tomorrow, we won't go to the park.
and why should it be this?

If it rains tomorrow, we won't go to the park.))

In the sense of "rain" falling from the sky you should say "it rains", where the word rain is a verb. "It is rain tomorrow" is an incorrect sentence; a "day" cannot be "rain"! You should say here "it'll rain tomorrow". However, with conditional "if" you don't use "will" in the same clause. So the correct sentence is "if it rains tomorrow, we won't go out", "if clause" takes the present simple when talking about the possible future.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's necessarily "incorrect", the ambiguity comes from the word "it" in this sentence.

"What is the weather forecast for tomorrow?"
"It is rain" --> the weather forecast is rain.

It's not regularly used this way though, a "normal" response would be "I've heard it'll be raining tomorrow"